# $A + A^{-1} = B$ find $A^{2} + A^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I found this exercise in mathematics course for medical engineering:

Matrix A fullfils condition:
$ A + A^{-1} = B$, where B = $ \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
2 & 3 & 4 \\
3 & 4 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}  $.

Find $C = A^{2} + A^{-1}$.

Has anybody idea how to crack this problem?

Comment: What have you tried ? where are you stuck ?

Comment: Raising B to power 2 hasn't help. B is symmetric, but not semi-positive definite so it's rather impossible to find solution by quadratic formula.

Comment: just to be sure there is not a typo, is it $A^2+A^{-1}$ or $A^2+A^{-2}$ ?

Comment: Unfortunately not, then raising B to power 2 makes all the work and it's trivial.

Comment: $B$ is symmetric, therefore it has an eigenbasis. Decompose it per the eigenbasis. Then you can look at each eigenspace separately

Comment: What material was this an exercise on?

Comment: Surprisingly it was the chapter about determinant and rank.

Comment: There is most likely a typo. As it currently stands, $A+A^{-1}=B$ has not any real solution but eight complex solutions. I think $A^2+A^{-1}$ should read $A^2+A^{-2}$.